# How do I retrieve the changed size of the DevExpress GridLookupEdit?

Tags: winforms, devexpress

I have a DevExpress GridLookupEdit.

I am able to change the popup's default size to whatever I want via:

```vb
theGrid.Properties.PopupFormSize = New Size(mywidth, myHeight)
```

However, I want to save the height/width for each user.

So I run the winform's program, click it, resize the window and then close the popup'd up control.

Then the `CloseUp` event fires. I check `theGrid.Properties.PopupFormSize` and the height and width are the same as my default values.

How do I get the resized values?

I am using DevExpress 13.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GridLookupEdit` uses `PopupGridLookUpEditForm` object to show popup contents and store it in `PopupForm` property. But size of this form is not equal to size that you can set through `GridLookupEdit.Properties.PopupFormSize` property. This form has an `EmbeddedControl` property and when you are changing `GridLookupEdit.Properties.PopupFormSize` property, you actually changing the size of this embedded control. So, if you want to save size for each user, you need to save size of this control.
Unfortunately `GridLookupEdit.PopupForm` property and `PopupGridLookUpEditForm.EmbeddedControl` property are protected. `PopupGridLookUpEditForm.EmbeddedControl` actually is `GridControl` object. For DevExpress 14.1 you can get this object through `GridLookupEdit.Properties.View.GridControl` property.
So in DevExpress 14.1 `GridLookupEdit.Properties.View.GridControl.Size` property is what you are looking for.
But if you cannot get `GridControl`object in your version then you can use reflection or create descendants.
Here example for reflection:

```cs
var popupFormProperty = theGrid.GetType().GetProperty("PopupForm", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, typeof(PopupGridLookUpEditForm), new Type[0], null);
var form = popupFormProperty.GetValue(theGrid);

var embeddedControlProperty = form.GetType().GetProperty("EmbeddedControl", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var embeddedControl = (Control)embeddedControlProperty.GetValue(form);//the size of this control is what you are looking for<
```

Another way is to create custom GridLookUp editor. According to [documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/CustomDocument4716) you need to create Custom Editor Class and Custom Repository Item Class, for example:

```cs
[UserRepositoryItem("RegisterCustomGridLookUpEdit")]
public class RepositoryItemCustomGridLookUpEdit : RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit
{
    static RepositoryItemCustomGridLookUpEdit() { RegisterCustomGridLookUpEdit(); }

    static public void RegisterCustomGridLookUpEdit()
    {
        EditorRegistrationInfo.Default.Editors.Add(
            new EditorClassInfo(CustomGridLookUpEditName,
            typeof(CustomGridLookUpEdit), typeof(RepositoryItemCustomGridLookUpEdit),
            typeof(GridLookUpEditBaseViewInfo), new ButtonEditPainter(), true, null));
    }

    public const string CustomGridLookUpEditName = "CustomGridLookUpEdit";

    public override string EditorTypeName { get { return CustomGridLookUpEditName; } }
}

public class CustomGridLookUpEdit : GridLookUpEdit
{
    static CustomGridLookUpEdit() { RepositoryItemCustomGridLookUpEdit.RegisterCustomGridLookUpEdit(); }

    public override string EditorTypeName { get { return RepositoryItemCustomGridLookUpEdit.CustomGridLookUpEditName; } }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public new RepositoryItemCustomGridLookUpEdit Properties
    {
        get { return base.Properties as RepositoryItemCustomGridLookUpEdit; }
    }

    protected override PopupBaseForm CreatePopupForm() { return new CustomPopupGridLookUpEditForm(this); }

    protected new CustomPopupGridLookUpEditForm PopupForm { get { return (CustomPopupGridLookUpEditForm)base.PopupForm; } }

    public Size PopupFormSize { get { return PopupForm.PopupFormSize; } }
}

public class CustomPopupGridLookUpEditForm : PopupGridLookUpEditForm
{
    public CustomPopupGridLookUpEditForm(CustomGridLookUpEdit ownerEdit) : base(ownerEdit) { }

    public Size PopupFormSize { get { return EmbeddedControl.Size; } }
}
```

If you add this `CustomGridLookUpEdit` to you project then you can use its `PopupFormSize` property to get the required size.

Comment: Thanks, for such a thorough answer. The first option (GridControl.Size) worked great for me.